# Why suddenly got the error "No gulpfile found"? Was working a few days ago

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, node-modules

I am using Mac, and using gulp with node.js. A few days ago, it was all working (compiled to CSS) when I typed "gulp sass"/ "gulp sass:watch", but suddenly today, I got the error message of "No Gulpfile Found" as I typed the same command, "gulp sass". 
I thought the gulp might be upgraded lately, and installed "gulp" again with "npm i -D gulp", but it hasn't changed anything.

I've just started learning programming a month ago, so forgive me not making a good question.
These are files I've got in my project file:

- gulpfile.js
- package-lock.json
- package.json
- node_modules
- sass

I appreciate your kind answers.

Comment: can you post the error

Comment: Tarun Kolla, actually, the error is only "No gulpfile found"..

Comment: In my gulpfile.js, these below are written 'use strict';
let gulp = require('gulp'); gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss').pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css'));gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', gulp.task(['sass']));
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a project named my-project and a package.json file is in your project directory. This is the same directory that contains a package.json file and is mentioned at the end of your question. You got a `No Gulpfile Found` error message when trying to run the `gulp sass` command. Make sure that you have changed directories with `cd` to this project directory before running `gulp sass`.

Comment: karel, Thank you very much for your kind answer! The issue was exactly because I was using gulp sass when I was in the wrong file. :)